# rank grep result by entries' timestamp

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to rank log entries by the timestamp of each entry.

let's say my grep result is like this, with each entry having different number of fields and time on different number of columns:

```
a, 3, time:123
b, time:124, 4
c, time:122, 5
```

how should I pipe the result such that it looks like this?

```
c, time:122, 5
a, 3, time:123
b, time:124, 4
```

Comment: `| sort -t: -n -k2`

Comment: @jhnc I edited my question to reciprocal my real problem, which have time on a different column depending on the log entry.

Comment: my code still works with your new sample data :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try the following:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   [[ $line =~ time:([0-9]+) ]] && printf "%s\t%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "$line"
done < file | sort -n | cut -f 2-
```

- It first extracts the time after the `time:` substring.
- Then it prepends the time before the line using a tab as a delimiter.
- It numerically sorts the lines.
- Finally it cuts off the 1st field.

Comment: No need to rearrange the fields, if you sort it directly according to  the value after the colon, as @jhnc explained it in his comment.

Comment: @user1934428 You're right. But if I (or whoever) post it as an answer (not in the comment), somebody else may remark what if other field contains a colon :)

Answer (score 1):

A general solution is:

1. for each line:

   - detect log format
   - extract timestamp column based on detected format
   - convert timestamp into sortable-form
   - print sortable-form + column delimiter + original line
2. pipe output of previous stage into something that sorts on the new first column
3. pipe output of previous stage into something that strips off the new first column